# Unity3d - How to make method calling from another class that belongs to another game object efficiently

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

This is the continuity from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460587/unity-changing-only-certain-part-of-3d-models-color).

What I want to do here is to create a program to calculate some score based on the 3D model's movement and show it as a change of model's color.

But since the model's movement recorder, score calculation, and coloring are from different classes attached on different Game Object, I need to make them connect to each other to work together.

I come up with the solution like below snippet, but the system got laggy and freezing. I am new to Unity world, so I ask you guys, is there any method more efficient to do this kind of job?

Here is my code structure in detail, so this problem is involving 3 different class calling each other (all attached to different game object)

**1) BoneHighlighter.cs**

to do some re-coloring on the model based on script from previous question

```cs
//declare SkinnedMeshRenderer
public SkinnedMeshRenderer smr;
//initialization
//previously put the initialization on Start(), but I try to put it on Awake() to make the initialization a bit sooner
void Awake () 
{
    if (smr == null) smr = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
    smr.sharedMesh = (Mesh)Instantiate(smr.sharedMesh);
}


// Change vertex colors highlighting given bone
public void Highlight(int index,double ratio = 1 ) 
{
    Transform[] bones = null;
    switch (index) 
    {
    case (int)Skeleton.Head:          bones = head;          break;
    case (int)Skeleton.UpperBody:     bones = upperBody;     break;
    case (int)Skeleton.LowerBody:     bones = lowerBody;     break;
    case (int)Skeleton.RightUpperArm: bones = upperArmRight; break;
    case (int)Skeleton.RightLowerArm: bones = lowerArmRight; break;
    case (int)Skeleton.RightHand:     bones = handRight;     break;
    case (int)Skeleton.LeftUpperArm:  bones = upperArmLeft;  break;
    case (int)Skeleton.LeftLowerArm:  bones = lowerArmLeft;  break;
    case (int)Skeleton.LeftHand:      bones = handLeft;      break;
    case (int)Skeleton.RightUpperLeg: bones = upperLegRight; break;
    case (int)Skeleton.RightLowerLeg: bones = lowerLegRight; break;
    case (int)Skeleton.RightFoot:     bones = footRight;     break;
    case (int)Skeleton.LeftUpperLeg:  bones = upperLegLeft;  break;
    case (int)Skeleton.LeftLowerLeg:  bones = lowerLegLeft;  break;
    case (int)Skeleton.LeftFoot:      bones = footLeft;      break;
    default: break;
    }

    //Debug.Assert(smr != null);
    if (smr != null) 
    {
        var mesh    = smr.sharedMesh;
        var weights = mesh.boneWeights;
        var colors  = new Color32[weights.Length];
        var sums    = new float[weights.Length];

        for (int j= 0; j<bones.Length; j++) 
        {
            var idx = GetBoneIndex (bones [j]);

            for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; ++i) 
            {
                float sum = 0;
                if (weights [i].boneIndex0 == idx && weights [i].weight0 > 0)
                    sum += weights [i].weight0;
                if (weights [i].boneIndex1 == idx && weights [i].weight1 > 0)
                    sum += weights [i].weight1;
                if (weights [i].boneIndex2 == idx && weights [i].weight2 > 0)
                    sum += weights [i].weight2;
                if (weights [i].boneIndex3 == idx && weights [i].weight3 > 0)
                    sum += weights [i].weight3;
                sums [i] += sum;
                colors [i] = Color32.Lerp (regularColor, highlightColor, sums [i] * (float)ratio);
                mesh.colors32 = colors;
            }

            //Debug.Log("bone index:\t"+bones[j].ToString());
        }
    } 
    else Debug.Log("smr null");
}
```

**2) Comparator.cs**

This is where I call `Highlight()` function, this class will return float number 0-1 to determine the intensity of the color. This is how I call the `Highlight()` function

```cs
//declare highlighter class as public variable
//drag & drop GameObject containing BoneHighlighter.cs from property inspector
public BoneHighlighter highlighter = null;

//calculate a score and pass it to highlight() function
private void calculateScore(int data)
{
    .
    .
    highlighter.Highlight(highlightedRegion, cost);
}
//get the data from other game object
public void GetData(Frame frame) 
{
    calculateScore((int)Skeleton.RightHand);
}
```

**3) Manager.cs**

This class is used to get a 3D model data each frame and pass it to Comparator.cs for score calculation

```cs
public Comparator comparatorClass = null;
void Update () 
{
    .
    .
    comparatorClass.GetData(frame);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First problem is with Highlight implementation. The line `mesh.colors32 = colors;` should not be inside for. This way you assign mesh.colors32 multiple times, but what matters is only the last time you assign it, all others are overwritten. Should be:

```
 for (int j= 0; j<bones.Length; j++) {

    var idx = GetBoneIndex (bones [j]);

    for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; ++i) {
        float sum = 0;
        if (weights [i].boneIndex0 == idx && weights [i].weight0 > 0)
            sum += weights [i].weight0;
        if (weights [i].boneIndex1 == idx && weights [i].weight1 > 0)
            sum += weights [i].weight1;
        if (weights [i].boneIndex2 == idx && weights [i].weight2 > 0)
            sum += weights [i].weight2;
        if (weights [i].boneIndex3 == idx && weights [i].weight3 > 0)
            sum += weights [i].weight3;
        sums [i] += sum;
        colors [i] = Color32.Lerp (regularColor, highlightColor, sums [i] * (float)ratio);
    }
}

mesh.colors32 = colors; // Finally, do it once
```

Making it a coroutine as it was suggested here is not needed, (and actually will make things worse).

2) Your **PRIMARY PROBLEM** is that you call `Highligh` on each `Update`. `Highlight` is not a very light function since it might need to access objects inside GPU memory when setting mesh colors. `Update` is called on each frame. You don't have to do `Highligh` on every frame - once something was highlighted, it will remain highlighted until "unhighlighted". You might want to call `Highlight`, only if something actually changed.

A simple way to do it is to remember what was highlighted on previous frame, and then highlight only if something changed. For example, your highlighter object may look like this:

```
//declare SkinnedMeshRenderer
public SkinnedMeshRenderer smr;
//initialization
//previously put the initialization on Start(), but I try to put it on Awake() to make the initialization a bit sooner
void Awake () 
{
    if (smr == null) smr = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
    smr.sharedMesh = (Mesh)Instantiate(smr.sharedMesh);
}

// Remember the index and ratio used last time to highlight.
private int prevIndex = -1;
private int prevRatio = -1;

// Change vertex colors highlighting given bone
public void Highlight(int index,double ratio = 1 ) 
{
    // If nothing changed, no need to highligh again - everything is already
    // highlighted. Break function execution.
    if (index == prevIndex && ratio == prevRatio) return;

    Transform[] bones = null;
    switch (index) 
    {
    case (int)Skeleton.Head:          bones = head;          break;
    case (int)Skeleton.UpperBody:     bones = upperBody;     break;
    case (int)Skeleton.LowerBody:     bones = lowerBody;     break;
    case (int)Skeleton.RightUpperArm: bones = upperArmRight; break;
    case (int)Skeleton.RightLowerArm: bones = lowerArmRight; break;
    case (int)Skeleton.RightHand:     bones = handRight;     break;
    case (int)Skeleton.LeftUpperArm:  bones = upperArmLeft;  break;
    case (int)Skeleton.LeftLowerArm:  bones = lowerArmLeft;  break;
    case (int)Skeleton.LeftHand:      bones = handLeft;      break;
    case (int)Skeleton.RightUpperLeg: bones = upperLegRight; break;
    case (int)Skeleton.RightLowerLeg: bones = lowerLegRight; break;
    case (int)Skeleton.RightFoot:     bones = footRight;     break;
    case (int)Skeleton.LeftUpperLeg:  bones = upperLegLeft;  break;
    case (int)Skeleton.LeftLowerLeg:  bones = lowerLegLeft;  break;
    case (int)Skeleton.LeftFoot:      bones = footLeft;      break;
    default: break;
    }

    //Debug.Assert(smr != null);
    if (smr != null) 
    {
        var mesh    = smr.sharedMesh;
        var weights = mesh.boneWeights;
        var colors  = new Color32[weights.Length];
        var sums    = new float[weights.Length];

        for (int j= 0; j<bones.Length; j++) 
        {
            var idx = GetBoneIndex (bones [j]);

            for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; ++i) 
            {
                float sum = 0;
                if (weights [i].boneIndex0 == idx && weights [i].weight0 > 0)
                    sum += weights [i].weight0;
                if (weights [i].boneIndex1 == idx && weights [i].weight1 > 0)
                    sum += weights [i].weight1;
                if (weights [i].boneIndex2 == idx && weights [i].weight2 > 0)
                    sum += weights [i].weight2;
                if (weights [i].boneIndex3 == idx && weights [i].weight3 > 0)
                    sum += weights [i].weight3;
                sums [i] += sum;
                colors [i] = Color32.Lerp (regularColor, highlightColor, sums [i] * (float)ratio);
            }

            //Debug.Log("bone index:\t"+bones[j].ToString());
        }

        mesh.colors32 = colors; // Finally, do it once
    } 
    else Debug.Log("smr null");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yeah the first one is my bad, when I fixed it, it works a lot faster. For the second problem, I think you are right, but I doubt by saving my previous state will solve the problem, since the ratio is pretty much changing every frame. I come up with several ideas, such as, mapping the mesh on initialization, so I already stored which mesh correspond to each bone, and iterate between those mesh only, instead of searching tho whole mesh. And maybe I will do Highlight on every 5/10 frames or so to make it faster

Answer (score 0):

1) Do you really have to call the `comparatorClass.GetData(frame);` on every update? if yes, then do you really need to call `highlighter.Highlight(highlightedRegion, cost);` on every update?

2) The other problem lies in the Highlight() method. You may want to move the following part:

```
 //Debug.Assert(smr != null);
if (smr != null) {
    var mesh = smr.sharedMesh;
    var weights = mesh.boneWeights;
    var colors = new Color32[weights.Length];
    var sums = new float[weights.Length];

    for (int j= 0; j<bones.Length; j++) {

        var idx = GetBoneIndex (bones [j]);

        for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; ++i) {
            float sum = 0;
            if (weights [i].boneIndex0 == idx && weights [i].weight0 > 0)
                sum += weights [i].weight0;
            if (weights [i].boneIndex1 == idx && weights [i].weight1 > 0)
                sum += weights [i].weight1;
            if (weights [i].boneIndex2 == idx && weights [i].weight2 > 0)
                sum += weights [i].weight2;
            if (weights [i].boneIndex3 == idx && weights [i].weight3 > 0)
                sum += weights [i].weight3;
            sums [i] += sum;
            colors [i] = Color32.Lerp (regularColor, highlightColor, sums [i] * (float)ratio);
            mesh.colors32 = colors;
        }


        //Debug.Log("bone index:\t"+bones[j].ToString());
    }
} else {
    Debug.Log("smr null");
}
```

into a co-routine and start that co routine only once for specific case. fo eg:

```
public void Highlight(int index,double ratio = 1 ) {
StopAllCoroutines(); // stop all co routines already running.
Transform[] bones = null;
switch (index) {
case (int)Skeleton.Head:
    bones = head;
    break;
case (int)Skeleton.UpperBody:
    bones = upperBody;
    break;
case (int)Skeleton.LowerBody:
    bones = lowerBody;
default:
    break;
 if(bones != null)
 {       
   startCoroutine(actualHighlight(bones));
 }

}
Ienumrator actualHighlight(Transform[] bones)
{
 if (smr != null) {
    var mesh = smr.sharedMesh;
    var weights = mesh.boneWeights;
    var colors = new Color32[weights.Length];
    var sums = new float[weights.Length];

    for (int j= 0; j<bones.Length; j++) {

        var idx = GetBoneIndex (bones [j]);

        for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; ++i) {
            float sum = 0;
            if (weights [i].boneIndex0 == idx && weights [i].weight0 > 0)
                sum += weights [i].weight0;
            if (weights [i].boneIndex1 == idx && weights [i].weight1 > 0)
                sum += weights [i].weight1;
            if (weights [i].boneIndex2 == idx && weights [i].weight2 > 0)
                sum += weights [i].weight2;
            if (weights [i].boneIndex3 == idx && weights [i].weight3 > 0)
                sum += weights [i].weight3;
            sums [i] += sum;
            colors [i] = Color32.Lerp (regularColor, highlightColor, sums [i] * (float)ratio);
            mesh.colors32 = colors;
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }


        //Debug.Log("bone index:\t"+bones[j].ToString());
    }
} else {
    Debug.Log("smr null");
 }
}
```

I hope this steers you into the right direction.